# Where does static variables and methods are loaded in java?

Tags: java

I am little bit confused that where did static variables and methods are loaded. we say that static variables and methods are loaded in the static memory. bt public static void main() is loaded into stack .Since main() method is also static then how it is possible that main is loaded into stack.
and alse is static methods and variable are stored in different positions because we say that methods are loaded in different place in memory.

Comment: First, the Java Virtual Machine manages it. Second, `static` variables are global in Java. And methods are not variables. But the JVM is responsible for loading the bytecode that contains the definitions of classes, the definitions of variables within classes, the initialization of said variables, and the invocation of methods (including parameter and return stacks). What problem are you trying to solve, and how does knowing this help you solve it?

Comment: Code is not "loaded" into the stack. Possibly you are confused between the concepts of code itself and the stack frame which is created to hold data related to the execution of an instance of that code (like local variables, saved registers, arguments, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The stack is where things go when they are invoked/executed.  It doesn't matter if it is static or not.  Any running function goes onto the stack where it's local variables and all are held until the stack frame is popped.

For example, I can have `main()` call `main()` recursively over and over.  Each one would be a new stack frame.  The fact that it is a static function does not change that.

Static variables, on the other hand, are different.  There will only be one instance of them and you know it explicitly.  So, they can go into special storage and be treated differently (as are other global things like the class definitions and all that).

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation of this is not liable to be very useful, nor easily understandable. However, a model of it might help you understand the use of these things.

First of all, data and code are quite different animals in Java. Variables are going to have values that change at runtime; code never does that. So when you instantiate a class, you are never going to get another copy of the code.

Consider the class `Class` - instances of it exist, one per fully-qualified class in the program. I think of all code for one class, static or not, as being associated with its `Class` instance -- 'loaded' with it, if you prefer. Incidentally, and coincidentally, that's also where I think of its static variables being 'loaded'.

But the instance variables need multiple copies -- whenever you instantiate the class, you need another copy of them. So they are associated (or loaded) with the instance of the class when instantiated -- think of the pointer to the class as a pointer to a structure that contains all the instance variables of that class, plus a pointer to jump tables to its methods, etc.

I do not know what you mean by `public static void main` being "loaded onto the stack". Do you mean the code? Code never goes onto a stack per se. It wouldn't make any sense to have code from a (normal) class put on the stack, lost when the current method returns, and then have to load it again if the method were called.

I think there's part of your question I'm not getting to because I don't understand what you're asking.